Extract row one by one from excel table, and save each extracted row individually as new excel file using loop
I have one header excel file (header.xlsx) with only one row, and one excel table file (station.xlsx) with multiple rows.
The aim is to extract first row from (station.xlsx), and then append the extracted first row to (header.xlsx), and then save them as new excel file called (1.xlsx).
After that, I want to extract second row from (station.xlsx), and then append the extracted second row to (header.xlsx), and then save them as (2.xlsx).
After that, I want to extract third row from (station.xlsx), and then append the extracted third row to (header.xlsx), and then save them as (3.xlsx)...
The loops will be continued until 167 rows from (station.xlsx) are extracted and append and save as new excel file individually.
# import module
import os
import openpyxl 
# load excel with its path 
wrkbk1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\kxz237\Desktop\test\header.xlsx") 
sh1 = wrkbk1.active
wrkbk2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\kxz237\Desktop\test\stations.xlsx") 
sh2 = wrkbk2.active

# iterate through excel and display data 
for i in range(1, sh2.max_row+1): 
    output_file = r'C:\Users\kxz237\Desktop\test\i.xlsx'
    sh1.append(sh2.row_values(i))
    wrkbk1.save(output_file)

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'row_values'
Could you help me fix the python code?
My original excel files are attached.enter link description here

Have you tried a search for that error message?

You have a Python text format error which is quite clear in it's explanation, or certainly can be researched on the internet as indicated by @cybernetic.nomad  and fixed. Though I wasn't aware that an Openpyxl Sheet object has an attribute row_values()

I have found a tutorial, here is an exact answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhVcJT47UjI

It's easy with pandas:
import pandas as pd

header = pd.read_excel(r"test\header.xlsx") 
df = pd.read_excel(r"test\stations.xlsx", header=None) 
 
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i,:].to_frame().T.to_excel(f'test/{i}.xlsx')

